# Is there a parameter for degree of ‘mixedness’

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, entropy, liquids

So I was making coffee this morning and when mixing some milk into the black coffee, I wondered if there was some parameter or value in chemistry which describes how well mixed two liquids (or gases) are.

Imagine water and oil in a beaker (I choose these because they can be completely separate). This parameter that I am thinking of could have a value of 0 where the water and oil are in completely separate layers. It would then have another value, say 1, when all molecules are perfectly mixed amongst each other (after a hypothetical, infinitely efficient shaking of the beaker).

Would this just be entropy or something derived from entropy? Or is there no such thing?

Comment: Just intuitively, it could be based on degree of sample homogenity and the sample/system mass or volume ratio.

Comment: The parameter you are looking for is the entropy, which is steadily increasing in mixing milk into the black coffee.

Comment: I have wondered about this as well, also in the context of miscible liquids, and for flow reactors.

Comment: I don’t see a way to measure the entropy change as mixing progresses, or to compare how it increases over time for different mixing methods. It would be interesting to have something measurable, so that different mixing methods could be compared. The measurable quantity might then be related to entropy through theoretical models.

Comment: Entropy of mixing is well defined, but when you mix there is always diffusion and convection and possibly mechanical stirring to consider so some volumes in the total will mix well before others so it will be a mess basically. If you put a dye into one liquid then measured the total absorption change throughout the whole spatial extent of the sample this might give a sort of average value vs time.

Comment: Don’t forget the enthalpy of mixing as well. The resulting G of the system vs composition determines if there will be phase separation or not.

Comment: Chemistry is messy, but the closest I can think of to what you have in mind is solubility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility Keep in mind that neither coffee nor milk would be considered homogeneous nor thermodynamically stable, so in that case it would be both difficult to reduce liquid-liquid miscibility to a single parameter.

Comment: Look up "solubles concentration" in the context of coffee preparation, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_extraction

Comment: From the perspective of engineering / physics, there is research about mixing coffee and milk to yield layered latte (e.g., this open access publication in 2017 [Nature Communications](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01852-2) echoed in NYTimes and [Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/physics-behind-layers-your-latte-180967546/)).